# Как сгенерировать случайное число кратное указанному числу?

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию которая генерирует случайное число в определенном диапазоне *(min, max)*, кратное указанному целому числу *(num)* ?

```
function getRandomX (min, max, num){
  /* какой-то код */
  return  result;
} 

//например: 
console.log(getRandomX(1, 6, 2)); // может вывести: 2, 4, 6  
console.log(getRandomX(1, 20, 5)); // может вывести: 5, 10, 15, 20
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function rand(min,max,num){
    return Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min) / num) * num;
}

console.log(rand(1, 6, 2));
console.log(rand(1, 20, 5));
```

Comment: Не подскажите с чем связан 0, который даже при минимальном 1 и 6 может вывестись?

Comment: @MoloF. `random` возвращает 0, +min -> 1 делим на num(2) -> 0.5 после отбрасывания дробной части получаем 0, умножаем на 2 - в итоге все равно 0

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сгенерировать случайное число в определенном диапазоне, кратное указанному целому числу нужно:

1. сгенерировать случайное число
2. проверить кратно ли оно заданному

   1. если кратно - вернуть
3. если не кратно

   1. получить ближайшее большее кратное
   2. если оно входит в интервал - вернуть
   3. если не входит - получить ближайшее меньшее кратное
   4. если оно входит в интервал - вернуть

```js
function rand(min, max, num) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  var rem = random % num;
  if (rem == 0) return random;

  var gross = random + num - rem;
  if (gross <= max) return gross;

  var less = random - rem;
  if (less >= min) return less;
}

console.log(rand(1, 6, 2));
console.log(rand(1, 20, 5));
```

В приведенном алгоритме не учитываются случаи, когда в интервал не попадает ни одно число кратное заданному.